# Why the use of "in" in Italian question titles?

Tags: word-usage, word-meaning, word-choice, prepositions, single-words

I'm very new to learning Italian and this has confused me about the site.  I know that "in" is translated nel or nello (if there are other forms, I'm as yet unaware).  In many question titles that are apparently asked in Italian, I still see the word "in" being used where I would have expected an Italian form of the word.

Has "in" been assimilated into Italian, has it always been a valid word to mean the same as it does in English, or is it just mixing of English and Italian in a sentence?

Comment: «"in" is translated nel or nello»: consider unfriending whomever made you think so.

Comment: And, as always, consulting a (Italian-English, English-Italian or Italian monolingual) vocabulary would have answered this doubt in ten seconds.

Comment: For instance, “the fridge is in the kitchen” would *not* be translated as *il frigo è nella cucina*, but *il frigo è in cucina* (no article in Italian in this case).

Comment: @DaG duolingo app on my phone.  I really don't like that they don't give you any of the hows and whys as to why things are the way they are.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

*Nel* means *in* + *il*, *nello* means *in* + *lo*, we call them *preposizioni articolate*, because *il* and *lo* are articles.

There are also *nella* = *in* + *la*, *nei* = *in* + *i*, *negli* = *in* + *gli* and *nelle* = *in* + *le*.

*In* is used also alone (as *preposizione semplice*), for example:

> In Italia si mangia bene.
>
> Oggi sono al mare ma domani devo andare in ufficio.

The *preposizioni semplici* are *di, a, da, in, con, su, per, tra, fra*.

The prepositions *di*, *a*, *da*, *in* and *su* have all the *forme articolate*.

For example: *del* = *di* + *il*, *allo* = *a* + *lo*, *dai* = *da* + *i*, etc.

For these prepositions you have to use the *forma articolata* if they are followed by an article:

> Correct: *Vado dalla nonna.*
>
> Wrong: *Vado da la nonna.*

*Con* is *articolata* with *il* = *col* and with *i* = *coi*, the other forms are less used or archaic.

In this case, however, also *con il* and *con i* are correct and probably more common:

> Correct: *Il gatto ha litigato col cane.*
>
> Correct: *Il gatto ha litigato con il cane.*

For the other prepositions the *forme articolate* don't exsist or are archaic.

Comment: Cool fact: _in_ is a Latin word that means _in_ and it didn't change in more than two millennia in both Italian and English.